# Access array of nested objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, nested-class

I have not been able to figure this out for quite sometime now after searching a lot of forums online.

I have a class A and a nested class B in a File A.java
Also another class C in File C.java

Now I declare an array of object B in class A but I can neither access nor initialize the array elements in Class A or Class C.

```
public class A{
    public B b[] = new B[15]; //compiles
    b[0] = new B(); //does not compile
    // b[0] = this.new B(); //does not compile either

    public class B{
    }

}
```

Now in Class C, if I do the following:

```
public class C{
A a = new A(); //compiles
a.b[0] = a.new A.B(); //does not compile
}
```

Can anyone please help? I think I am doing some basic error in syntax while trying to access nested instance arrays. Thanks!

Comment: `B` needs to be declared `static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second line `b[0] = new B();`  should be inside any method
.Do like this

```
package com.sample;

public class A {
    public B[] b = new B[15];

    /*
     * public A() {
        b[0] = new B();
    *}

    */

    public class B {
    }
}
```

C.java

```
 package com.sample;

public class C {
    A a = new A();
    public C()
    {
        A a=new A();
        a.b[0]=a.new B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `A` to access `B` class constructor. You are already accessing it on `A` class instance. Just change your statement to:

```
a.b[0] = a.new B();
```

**Reference:**

- [Oracle Tutorial - Inner Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

And of course, that assignment has to be inside some method, constructor, or initializers. You can't have statements directly inside a class just like that. Same issue with the assignment in class `A`.

So, you should change class `C` to something like this:

```
class C {
    A a = new A(); //compiles

    {
        a.b[0] = a.new B(); 
    }
}
```